# Pass a selected value through ajax onchange event

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a select form:

```
<form id="form" name="nameForm">

<select id="selectId" onchange="loadAjax('url.php');return false;">
<option>One</option
<option>Two</option>
</select>

</form>
```

I want that when the user changes the selected option, it loads the ajax function with the value in the url (trough GET).

So I tried several things and this was my last try:

```
onchange="
var e = document.getElementById('form');
var strSel = e.form.selectId.value;
loadAjax('url.php?v='+strSel);
return false; 
">
```

Not really correct. Does someone know how to do this correctly ?

Comment: take a look at `jquery` your life will be much easier.

Comment: thanks but I'm not using Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing **value attribute** in `options`

I tried it and it works after adding **value**, like,

```
<select id="selectId" onchange="alert('url.php?v='+this.value);return false;">
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

You should try this,

```
<select id="selectId" onchange="loadAjax('url.php?v='+this.value);return false;">
   <option value="one">One</option>
   <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3AAy/)

Answer (score 1):

According to your code sample this will work

```
onchange="
var e = document.getElementById('selectId');
var strSel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
loadAjax('url.php?v='+strSel);
return false; 
">
```